# How to add Lewis Structures to a question or an answer?

Tags: support

I've been here for just a few days and almost $ 3/4th $ of those few days I've been trying to find out the thing mentioned in the heading. I get absolutely no results when I search for it. And when I search Lewis Structures all I find is this : [What are options for type-setting high quality Lewis structures?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4811/102062)
and some other irrelevant results. Everything that I know about writing them comes from that code fragment that @andselisk has given  in his answer to the above question. Please help me in this matter.

Please don't misunderstand me. I'm not asking you people to teach me how to draw these. I just want to know how I can add them to my answers or questions.

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not a question about this site, so it is definitely off topic here. You should be aware that drawing Lewis structures is a very, very basic concept, which is explained in every entry-level chemistry textbook. You should definitely read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_structure) article before asking this question, because I have a strong feeling it'll be closed immediately. (And please do not abuse MathJax as a text styling element.)

Comment: Sorry, @Martin you just misunderstood me. I'm not talking about  how to draw them. I meant how to add them to my answers. I already know how to draw them. I just want to know how I can add them to my questions or answers.

Comment: Save it as an image and then add the image to the post. Using the `chemfig` package is nearly always more hassle than it's worth, in my experience. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/37880#37880 for a list of software that you can use to draw them.

Comment: Ohh thank you @orthocresol . It was so kind of you to help this poor newbie :)

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from the [one OP mentioned](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4811). Should we probably close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @orthocresol True, `chemfig` is hard, and, with changing syntax and French English documentation, sometimes evil, but it is a necessary evil. I don't know any other decent drawing tool with comparable extensibility and freedom, even though it's freedom as in shooting own leg, mostly:)

Comment: @andselisk I actually appreciate the work that has gone into `chemfig`, and I've used it myself for some old, old notes. But one can't get around the fact that TeX was really not designed with that sort of thing in mind. What we need is of course a free version of ChemDraw, free in the sense that you mean ;-) I have wondered on several occasions if it is possible to script Inkscape for this purpose.

Comment: @orthocresol Agree, tables and drawing isn't TeX bread and butter, but Inkscape also has its quirks. The biggest pain is it's GTK, and they really like to rewrite things from the ground up and to break compatibility (and common sense, with GNOME 3 design choices). Plus, they really like to stress out that Inkscape is a tool for artists (and it shows), which I kinda interpret as a warning sign to use it for scientific purposes with a caution.

Comment: I saw this site that looks interesting:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=c11e9ad0ab00998884f0733c8f62c07d and I could put it up as answer for you if it is helpful;  keep in mind that cut and paste of images might require a certain level of reputation (along with copyright permission of course); but the link to the original may not require this.  For one of the Stack Exchange websites where I did not have enough reputation to post the image, I got help from another user for one equation picture post.  The correct diagram is linked, and can be redrawn by hand or w/ Libre Draw.